# perl regex find & replace

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am trying to remove some garbage js code on 4k+ webpages. The webpages have other js on the page as well so I need to only get rid of the JS with a particular function called clickIE.

I have this one liner working until I introduce the regex...

```
perl -p -i -e 's|<script(.*)>.*clickie.*?<\/script>|<\!--REMOVED-JS-CODE-->|gixsm' ./*.html
```

My regex works correctly when tested at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ but fails on the command line...(fails meaning... the regex doesnt match anything)

Comment: Why are you using greedy instead of lazy matching? What *specifically* do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: @MarkByers your suggestion tightened it up. Thanks. Its working just fine when I test it at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/.   When I run it from the command line it doesn't do the replacement. `perl -p -i -e 's|<script(.*?)>.*?clickie.*?<\/script>|<\!--REMOVED-JS-CODE-->|gixsm' ./*.html`

Comment: This trips over `<script>console.log("clickie")</script>`. Admittedly, it's unlikely that you'll find 'clickie' in quotes anywhere in the sources you're looking at, but in the general case that may be less likely.

Fixing this safely involves using a javascript parser to only find cases where the target string is being used as a function name, which is a somewhat harder problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the regex to work, the entire file needs to be slurped in at once.

```
$ perl -0777 -pi -e 's/your/regex/gix' ./*.html
```

Comment: +1 Foiled me by 1 minute again, with the exact solution I was going to suggest. =P You may need to keep the flags, though.

Comment: @TLP : There is always one more way to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Mark the matches should be non-greedy. This seems to work...

```
perl -i -p -e 's|<script.*?>.*?clickie.*?</script>|<!-- removed -->|gism'
```